# How to differentiate signin and signup user in firebase using google auth?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase to authenticate user. If new user signin using google/facebook provider, it creates a user and automatically sign in. After user signin, how to differentiate between signIn and signUp?

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  var user = result.user;
  // if new user i want to redirect to some other page.
  // if user already exist, i want to redirect to home page
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
});
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [`UserCredential` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#usercredential) you get as `result` has an [`additionalUserInfo` member](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#additionaluserinfo) that has an [`isNewUser` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#isnewuser:-boolean).

So `result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser` will be true the first time the user signs in, and false afterwards.

Comment: Is this answer out of date with the latest Firebase? I'm not seeing the `isNewUser` property on the object

Comment: It's still there in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.additionaluserinfo If you're having a hard time finding it in your situation I recommend posting a new question with its own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

use `getAdditionalUserInfo`

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

firebase
  .auth()
  .signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then(function (result) {
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    var user = result.user;
    const additionalUserInfo = getAdditionalUserInfo(userCredential);
    if (additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
      // if new user i want to redirect to some other page.
    } else {
      // if user already exist, i want to redirect to home page
    }
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
  });
```