# How to redirect a user based on Firebase Authentication status?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to redirect users when they sign in with Github or others based on whether they are a new user or a returning user. I'm having trouble accessing the isNewUser property referenced in this answer: [How to differentiate signin and signup user in firebase using google auth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61700450/how-to-differentiate-signin-and-signup-user-in-firebase-using-google-auth)

I have a standard sign in function:

```
const signinWithGoogle = () => {
    return auth.signInWithPopup(googleProvider)
    .then((response) => {
        handleUser(response.user)
    })
}
```

This is the handleUser function:

```
const handleUser = (rawUser) => {
    if (rawUser) {
        const currentUser = formatUser(rawUser)
        createUser(currentUser.uid, currentUser)
        setCurrentUser(currentUser)
        if (currentUser.providerData[0].isNewUser===true) {
            history.push("/onboarding")
        } else {
            history.push("/")
        }
        return currentUser
    }
    else {
        setCurrentUser(false)
        return false
    }
}
```

And this is formatUser:

```
const formatUser = (user) => {
return {
    uid: user.uid,
    email: user.email,
    name: user.displayName,
    provider: user.providerData[0].providerId,
    avatar: user.photoURL,
}
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, please?

Cheers, Matt

EDIT:

If we pass the response to the HandleUser function and console log response.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser we get 'true'. However, if we use that in our if statement, it seems to be ignored for some reason

```
const handleUser = (response) => {
    if (response) {
        console.log("response: ", response.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser)
        const currentUser = formatUser(response.user)
        createUser(currentUser.uid, currentUser)
        setCurrentUser(currentUser)
        console.log('response', response)
        console.log('additional info', response.additionalUserInfo)
        const isNew = response.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser
        console.log('isNewUser', isNewUser)
        if (isNew) {
            console.log('redirecting to /onboarding')
            history.push("/onboarding")
        } else {
            console.log('redirecting to /')
            history.push("/")
        }
        return currentUser
    }
    else {
        setCurrentUser(false)
        return false
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: Here is the output from the console logs

[image]

That error is coming from the signInWithGithub function in the modal

```
async function signInGitHub() {
    try {
        await signinWithGitHub()
    }

    catch(err) {
        console.log("Error: ",err.code)
    }

    finally {
        closeModal();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Matt, if the answer was helpful you can answer/upvote it else feel free to ask further queries. The updated issue (undefined error) seems to be a different issue and it'll be ideal to post another question for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are passing a [User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) to that function and not the raw response. The `isNewUser` is present on the [additionalUserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#additionaluserinfo) property. Please try refactoring as shown below:

```
const handleUser = (rawUser) => {
    if (rawUser) {
        const currentUser = formatUser(rawUser.user)
        createUser(currentUser.uid, currentUser)
        setCurrentUser(currentUser)
        if (currentUser.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
            history.push("/onboarding")
        } else {
            history.push("/")
        }
        return currentUser
    }
    else {
        setCurrentUser(false)
        return false
    }
}
```

Also make sure you pass the raw response:

```
handleUser(response.user)
```

Comment: Hi Dharmaraj, thanks for your time. It's still sending the user straight to ("/") when signing up as a new user. I can't understand why. Also, I had to change your code back to const currentUser = formatUser(rawUser) as rawUser.user caused the createUser function to fail.

Comment: @MattHeslington can you please log "response" and share it?

Comment: additionalUserInfo: rg {providerId: "github.com", isNewUser: true, profile: {…}, username: "MattHeslington"}
credential: Kg {a: null, accessToken: "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", providerId: "github.com", signInMethod: "github.com"}
operationType: "signIn"
user: Im {J: Array(0), l: "AIzaSyDHy0Mtp0ZFqV5kMa5WzVGNSIGKPeeazpk", m: "[DEFAULT]", s: "d-production.firebaseapp.com", a: Ii, …}

Comment: @MattHeslington I do see the `isNewUser` property there. Is that 'response' that you logged?

Comment: Hi Dharmaraj, I just editing my post. Yes, we have a additionalUserInfo object - please check my edit

Comment: @MattHeslington I've updated your code with log statements, can you please run it and share a screenshot of output? (screenshot please)

Comment: @MattHeslington it doesn't seem to be an issue there tbh, I do see an error in the LoginModal.js. A last try could be adding log statements in the if else to check it. 
`const isNew = response.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser`
`if (isNewUser) { console.log('redirecting to onboading'); (redirect) }`